# files not updating in meteor local environment

Tags: meteor

I've got everything set-up and my app is live on port 3000.

My problem is, any updates I make to files such as adding new elements to views, styles etc in don't update automatically.

I've tried running in -w but to no avail.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are there any error in the browser console?

Comment: more details? your running the command "meteor" in your terminal to start the server and then leaving it running while editing files in another shell window/editor? something to do with browser cache possibly, have you tried emptying that?

Comment: any error on the server?